# Querying Nested object/table sqlalchemy ORM

Tags: python, oracle, sqlalchemy, orm, fastapi

I have table that have a deeply nested relationship with other tables

```
@mapper_registry.mapped
@dataclass
class Project:
    __tablename__ = "project"
    __table_args__ = (#some table constraints here)

    id: float = field(init=False, metadata={"sa": Column(NUMBER(15, 0, False), primary_key=True)})
    date_created: datetime = field(metadata={"sa": Column(MyTimestamp, nullable=False)})
    user_created_id: float = field(metadata={"sa": Column(NUMBER(15, 0, False), nullable=False)})
    user_created: Optional[BiologicsUser] = field(default=None, metadata={"sa": relationship("User", foreign_keys="Project.user_created_id", backref="project")})
    
    
mapper_registry.mapped
@dataclass
class User:
    __tablename__ = "user"
    __table_args__ = ()
    __sa_dataclass_metadata_key__ = "sa"

    id: float = field(
        init=False, metadata={"sa": Column(NUMBER(15, 0, False), primary_key=True)}
    )
    name: str = field(metadata={"sa": Column(VARCHAR(100), nullable=False)})
    organization_id: Optional[float] = field(default=None, metadata={"sa": Column(NUMBER(15, 0, False))})
    department_id: Optional[float] = field(default=None, metadata={"sa": Column(NUMBER(15, 0, False))})
    site_id: Optional[float] = field(default=None, metadata={"sa": Column(NUMBER(15, 0, False))})
    department: Optional[Department] = field(default=None,metadata={"sa": relationship("Department", backref="user")})
    organization: Optional[Organization] = field(default=None,metadata={"sa": relationship("Organization", backref="user")})
    site: Optional[Site] = field(default=None,metadata={"sa": relationship("Organization", backref="user")})
    
    

@dataclass
class Department:
    __tablename__ = "department"
    __table_args__ = ( )
    __sa_dataclass_metadata_key__ = "sa"

    id: float = field(init=False, metadata={"sa": Column(NUMBER(15, 0, False), primary_key=True)})
    label: str = field(metadata={"sa": Column(VARCHAR(255), nullable=False)})

@dataclass
class Organization:
    __tablename__ = "organization"
    __table_args__ = ( )
    __sa_dataclass_metadata_key__ = "sa"

    id: float = field(init=False, metadata={"sa": Column(NUMBER(15, 0, False), primary_key=True)})
    label: str = field(metadata={"sa": Column(VARCHAR(255), nullable=False)})
    
@dataclass
class Site:
    __tablename__ = "site"
    __table_args__ = ( )
    __sa_dataclass_metadata_key__ = "sa"

    id: float = field(init=False, metadata={"sa": Column(NUMBER(15, 0, False), primary_key=True)})
    label: str = field(metadata={"sa": Column(VARCHAR(255), nullable=False)})
```

When I query project using

```
session.execute(select(Project)).all()
```

I got a nested dictionary/object for all the columns in the project and nested user_created column as expected. But I dont need to return all of this as it is a large tree of nested object. So I tried specifying the needed fields

When I try to select the id and user_created `select(Project.id, Project.user_created)` for example I got the error

```
ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected
E   Help: https://docs.oracle.com/error-help/db/ora-00923/
E   [SQL: SELECT project.id, user.id = project.user_created_id AS anon_1
E   FROM project, user]  - sqlalchemy.exc.DatabaseError: (oracledb.exceptions.DatabaseError) ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected
```

My naive thought was that since I can get all the columns including the nested one, I should be able to just select the columns that I needed and get all the nested column loaded. so I tried     `query = select(Project).options(load_only(Project.id, Project.user_created))`

got the error

```
Can't apply "column loader" strategy to property "Project.user_created", which is a "relationship"; this loader strategy is intended to be used with a "column property".
```

So I changed `query = select(Project).options(load_only(project.id), selectinload(Project.user_created))`

Still failed. Not really sure what am I doing wrong.

Comment: Can you make a [mre] please?  Let's remove any tables and columns that aren't required to reproduce the error, and make sure that example is runnable standalone.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit confusing but I think the key issue is the blurred distinction between column and relationship.  Something like `project.id` is a column versus `project.user_created` is a relationship, ie. another model.  You have to treat these differently.  You can check what happens by setting `echo=True` on your engine.

Here are a couple of examples:

###### A. Working with pure-orm you can limit the project object to only containing an `id` column and then loading the `user_created` relationship with another query.

```py
q = select(Project).options(load_only(Project.id), selectinload(Project.user_created))
for project in session.scalars(q):
    print (project.id, project.user_created.id)
```

###### B. Selecting the `id` column and the `user_created` object but you have to specify the join yourself, this should use a single query.

```py
q = select(Project.id, Project.user_created).join(Project.user_created)
for project_id, project_user_created in session.execute(q):
    print (project.id, project.user_created.id)
```

Comment: Also I don't know much about oracle but why are the ids `float`s, is that a normal thing?

Comment: Good observation on `float`. lets just say this project is mirroring another legacy project that defines the database. oracle NUMBER with precision 15 was used for all numeric fields. The ID at the end of the day is just `x.0`. 
Not very sure, but just assume float is less complicated since precision does not really matter. `INTEGER` will have suffice for the internal declaration for the `ID`s

Comment: **OPTION A:** for each `Project.id` is it making a new call to the `User` table hence, took forever to complete execution.

***OPTION B** does not work at all
**
sqlalchemy.exc.DatabaseError: (oracledb.exceptions.DatabaseError) ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected
E   Help: https://docs.oracle.com/error-help/db/ora-00923/
E   [SQL: SELECT project.id, user.id = project.user_created_id AS anon_1
E  project JOIN  user  ON user.id = project.user_created_id
E   (Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/20/4xp6)

Comment: This seems to work for whatever reason

`query = select(Project.id, User).join(User, Project.user_created_id == User.id)`

Comment: Thank you for the `echo=True`. I find that very healpful

Comment: What version of sqlalchemy are you using ?